# What are the two groups that are bijective, but not isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I need to come up with two groups that are bijective, but not isomorphic.
So I thought about 
the map $L_g: G \rightarrow G'$. $L_g(x) = gx$.

$L_g: x \rightarrow gx$   Correct

$L_{g^-1}: gx \rightarrow x$ Doesn't work.

I am a little confused why the group is not isomorphic. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your $L_g$ function is a bijection, and not a homorphism, so it's not an isomorphism.  But the domain and image are the same group $G$, which is obviously isomorphic to itself.

Comment: You want two groups which can be put in one-to-one correspondence but which are not isomorphic.  For instance, do you know of two finite groups of the same order that are not isomorphic?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Thank you for your response. Z2 x Z2 and Z4 are not isomorphic. However, how can I see that they are bijective?

Comment: There's always a bijection between any two finite sets with the same number of elements. $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$ both have $4$ elements.

Comment: @Pythoner1234 You actually have $4!$ choices for bijections, as all you are doing is picking renaming of elements.

Comment: I know what a bijective map is. I never heard of bijective groups (or bijective sets). What do you mean by bijective groups?

Answer (score 2):

Take the set of numbers $G=\{1,3,5,7\}$ with binary operation being  multiplication modulo 8. Check that this is a group. Now consider $U=\{1,-1, +i, -i\}$; this is also a group, but now for the operation of multiplication of complex numbers.

As both have 4 elements they are bijective. Any bijection one can construct between these two groups will never be a homomorphism. (one is cyclic other is not).

Answer (score 2):

You can take two groups with the same number of elements and different structural features. This is a good strategy for showing any two groups are not isomorphic. One good class of differentiating structural features are those that arise from the group's binary operation. One that might come to mind is commutativity. Certainly, if one group is abelian, and the other nonabelian, no homomorphism can be found between the two.

So, for one of our groups, let's take $S_3$, the symmetry group with $3! = 6$ elements. This group is nonabelian (if you don't know this, it's easy to exhibit via the Cayley diagram of $S_3$). Then take $\langle \mathbb{Z}_6, + \rangle$, the integers modulo six equipped with integer addition. We know that $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is abelian, as integer addition is commutative. But $S_3$, as I mentioned, is nonabelian. However, they both have six elements, so a bijection exists between their sets. But no homomorphism can ever exist, so they are not isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest case is $C_4$ the cyclic group of order 4 and $C_2 \times C_2$, the Klein group.

Comment: Just to point out a feature that demonstrates they are not isomorphic: $C_4$ has an element of order four, but every element of the Klein group has order at most two.  (I also like this answer for "simplest" because any cardinality less than four has exactly one isomorphism class.)

Comment: @kyle exact no less